# What is the name of font used in GNU Image Manipulation Program (GIMP)?

Tags: fonts, gimp, photo-editing

What is the name of the font used on buttons and other elements of the [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) GUI?

[image: a screen capture of part of the program's graphic user interface]

Comment: What platform are you on? It will be a system font, therefore vary by system. Mine looks completely different - & on Mac, GIMP fonts are generally terrible… so I've always assumed they put their effort into Windows.

Comment: It’s… “Sans”. Whatever that might be on your system (which you do not specify).

Comment: I have Gimp 2.1 on Ubuntu and no mention of fonts. No serifs so some kind of San Serif.